# Как передать класс в конструктор в Python

Tags: python, классы, telebot

Пишу телеграмм-бота со встроенным календарем (из библиотеки `telegram_bot_calendar`)

Столкнулся с проблемой, что календарь на англ языке, однако нагуглил, как его перевести.

```
from telegram_bot_calendar import DetailedTelegramCalendar, LSTEP

your_translation_months = list('январь, февраль, март, апрель, май, июнь, июль, август, сентябрь, октябрь, ноябрь, декабрь')

your_translation_days_of_week = list('ПонедельникВторникСредаЧетвергПятницаСубботаВоскресенье')


class MyTranslationCalendar(DetailedTelegramCalendar):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.days_of_week['yourtransl'] = your_translation_days_of_week
        self.months['yourtransl'] = your_translation_months
```

Но не могу додумать, как добавить этот класс в конструктор:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['calendar'])


def start(message):
    calendar, step = DetailedTelegramCalendar().build()
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                     f"Select {LSTEP[step]}",
                     reply_markup=calendar)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=DetailedTelegramCalendar.func())
def cal(call):
    result, key, step = DetailedTelegramCalendar().process(call.data)
    if not result and key:
        bot.edit_message_text(f"Select {LSTEP[step]}",
                              call.message.chat.id,
                              call.message.message_id,
                              reply_markup=key)
    elif result:
        bot.edit_message_text(f"You selected {result}",
                              call.message.chat.id,
                              call.message.message_id)
```

Не судите за глупые вопросы, изучая Python, взялся за небольшой проект, дабы прокачать скилл на практике!

Всем спасибо!

Comment: Где конструктор и где класс?

Comment: Просто замените в своём коде телеграм бота использование класса `DetailedTelegramCalendar` на `MyTranslationCalendar` и всё.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то просто заменяете использование старого класса на новый у себя везде, и всё. Т.е. старый код:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['calendar'])
def start(message):
    calendar, step = DetailedTelegramCalendar().build()
    ...
```

Заменить на:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['calendar'])
def start(message):
    calendar, step = MyTranslationCalendar().build()
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ...
```

И так везде в коде бота.

Answer (score 0):

Можно просто использовать: DetailedTelegramCalendar(local='ru')

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/794056)